# Hover no SVG na minha página não responde

Tags: css, svg, css-hover

Eu estou tentando criar um círculo com diversas divisões em SVG, e cada seção ao passar o mouse, eu gostaria que a cor de fundo mudasse.
No entanto o código que eu estou tentando usar não está funcionando. Adicionei a classe "t3-30" no quadrado que quero mudar a cor de fundo quando passar o mouse sobre, porém na página somente o xlink funciona, o mouse hover não...

[image: Circulo]

Código SVG:

```
 <a xlink:href="#">
    <path class ='t3-30'
    style="fill:#f2f2f2;stroke:none;stroke-width:7.38895512;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none"
    d="m 242.86651,56.159949 c -5.21279,-12.38751 -9.12939,-22.869949 -8.70354,-23.29431 3.2411,-3.22978 63.66868,-22.054228 65.23154,-20.320981 0.5617,0.622944 10.81001,47.586663 10.81001,49.537777 0,0.528169 -1.97943,0.973262 -4.39874,0.989096 -2.4193,0.01584 -14.8183,3.534825 -27.55333,7.819977 -12.73502,4.285154 -23.77414,7.791188 -24.53136,7.791188 -0.75722,0 -5.64178,-10.135236 -10.85458,-22.522747 z"
    id="path50499"
    inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
    transform="matrix(0.26458333,0,0,0.26458333,4.9999997,48.5)" /> </a>
```

Código do CSS:

```
.t3-30:hover {
fill: #ffff00;
```

}

Não postei o código inteiro do SVG aqui porque é longo demais.
Criei o mesmo no Inkscape, e o cabeçalho é assim:

```
<svg
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
width="100mm"
height="100mm"

viewBox="0 0 200 200"
version="1.1"
id="svg8"
sodipodi:docname="daily_calendar.svg"
inkscape:version="0.92.3 (2405546, 2018-03-11)">
<defs
    id="defs2" />
<sodipodi:namedview
    id="base"
    pagecolor="#ffffff"
    bordercolor="#666666"
    borderopacity="1.0"
    inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
    inkscape:pageshadow="2"
    inkscape:zoom="0.51151044"
    inkscape:cx="585.46772"
    inkscape:cy="285.44195"
    inkscape:document-units="mm"
    inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
    showgrid="false"
    inkscape:snap-center="true"
    inkscape:snap-object-midpoints="true"
    inkscape:snap-midpoints="true"
    inkscape:snap-smooth-nodes="true"
    inkscape:snap-intersection-paths="true"
    inkscape:object-nodes="true"
    inkscape:snap-nodes="true"
    inkscape:snap-others="true"
    inkscape:snap-grids="true"
    inkscape:snap-to-guides="true"
    inkscape:object-paths="true"
    inkscape:snap-bbox="true"
    inkscape:bbox-nodes="true"
    inkscape:bbox-paths="true"
    inkscape:snap-bbox-midpoints="true"
    inkscape:snap-bbox-edge-midpoints="true"
    inkscape:snap-page="true"
    showguides="false"
    inkscape:window-width="1366"
    inkscape:window-height="715"
    inkscape:window-x="-8"
    inkscape:window-y="-8"
    inkscape:window-maximized="1" />

<g
    inkscape:label="Camada 1"
    inkscape:groupmode="layer"
    id="layer1"
    transform="translate(-4.9999997,-48.5)">
    <circle
    style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none"
    id="path3723"
    cx="105"
    cy="148.5"
```

.
.
.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Não ta funcionando esse svg! poste ele completo no pastebin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara como vc não colocou o seu código inteiro do SVG eu tive que fazer um para poder usar de exemplo aqui.

A primeira coisa que vc pode fazer é colocar um `fill:transparent` no vetor, pois sem o `fill` (`fill:none`) ele não vai reconhecer o `:hover`, pois é como se ele não tivesse uma "área ativa" então coloque um `fill` mesmo que transparente para evitar qq bug de `:hover`

Depois basta fazer o css do `:hover` direto no .css ou se preferir dentro do `<defs><style>` no próprio SVG, no caso eu fiz no css externo só pra facilitar.

Veja como ficou o exemplo: ***(Passe o mouse na célula 2C)***

```css
rect {stroke:black;stroke-width:1;fill:transparent;}
text {user-select: none; pointer-events: none;}
.teste:hover {fill:red;stroke:green;stroke-width:3;}
```

```html
<svg width="403" height="302" viewBox="0 0 403 302" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <rect width="100" height="100"/>
        <rect x="101" width="100" height="100"/>
        <rect x="202" width="100" height="100"/>
        <rect x="303" width="100" height="100"/>
        <rect y="101" width="100" height="100"/>
        <rect x="101" y="101" width="100" height="100"/>
        <rect class="teste" x="202" y="101" width="100" height="100"/>
        <rect x="303" y="101" width="100" height="100"/>
        <rect y="202" width="100" height="100"/>
        <rect x="101" y="202" width="100" height="100"/>
        <rect x="202" y="202" width="100" height="100"/>
        <rect x="303" y="202" width="100" height="100"/>
        <text x="202" y="121" fill="blue">2C</text>
</svg>
```

---

SVG puro com o `Style` no `<defs>`

Clique em **Expandir** abaixo:

```html
<svg width="403" height="302" viewBox="0 0 403 302" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <style>
            rect {stroke:black;stroke-width:1;fill:transparent;}
            text {user-select: none; pointer-events: none;}
            .teste:hover {fill:red;stroke:green;stroke-width:3;}
        </style>
    </defs>
    <rect width="100" height="100"/>
    <rect x="101" width="100" height="100"/>
    <rect x="202" width="100" height="100"/>
    <rect x="303" width="100" height="100"/>
    <rect y="101" width="100" height="100"/>
    <rect x="101" y="101" width="100" height="100"/>
    <rect class="teste" x="202" y="101" width="100" height="100"/>
    <rect x="303" y="101" width="100" height="100"/>
    <rect y="202" width="100" height="100"/>
    <rect x="101" y="202" width="100" height="100"/>
    <rect x="202" y="202" width="100" height="100"/>
    <rect x="303" y="202" width="100" height="100"/>
<text x="202" y="121" fill="blue">2C</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Obrigado hugocsl! Pelo que pude entender, o problema é que o fill:none é que causa o problema? Porém no path que quero implementar o hover está com fill: fill:#f2f2f2.

Comment: @FernandoFerrariFernandes não necessariamente é o fill, o fill poderia ser um dos problemas... mas se o shape já tem uma cor o seu problema pode ser com o CSS e o :hover, tente fazer um teste com um SVG mais simples e tentar mudar a cor no :hover pra ver como fica. Se o seu SVG for em `<path>` verifique se o Path esta fechado e se o preenchimento está mesmo no fundo ou só no contorno desse Path, vc pode testar isso rapidamente colocando uma cor de background no Body e ver se o seu SVG realmente está com cor ou se vc está vendo a cor do fundo por entre as linhas do svg...

Comment: Legal. Deu certo era exatamente a questão do preenchimento como você mencionou e resolveu meu problema. Muito obrigado!

Comment: @FernandoFerrariFernandes que bom que resolver, se vc acha que o problema foi resolvido considere marcar a Resposta como Aceita **✓** assim ela não fica pendente no site como pegunta não respondia.

Comment: Eu postei outra... nao resolveu nao... o erro continua quando o svg é mais elaborado. postei outra pergunta com o codigo completo

Comment: @FernandoFerrariFernandes vou dar uma olhada

Comment: Puxa muito obrigado! Eu até peço desculpas sou novo no uso de SVG (é minha primeira vez) e é um projeto importante, sua ajuda tem sido muito legal!

Comment: @FernandoFerrariFernandes eu tb não entendo muito da SVG só um básico mesmo. Vou ver o que consigo averiguar rss. As vezes o problema pode ser com o SVG final que é gerado pelo Software que vc usou, e não com o SVG em si entende... Ai realmente eu não vou conseguir resolver, só tentando refazer em outro software, mas vamos ver primeiro o que consigo aqui com seu código

Comment: @FernandoFerrariFernandes como falei a forma como os vetores foram gerados pelo Software não ficou legal, por isso o preenchimento das células não fica tão bom. Mas no geral acho que resolveu o problema lá. Da uma olhada na outra resposta que tem os detalhes